# Can't access cookie instantly after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I've made a "php listener" that receives a AJAX post and sets a cookie and after that redirects to the next step /step/1/.

On that page it will first check if the cookie $_COOKIE['register'] has been set, if not then redirect to step 1.

I've saw a lot of duplicate posts but not one with a clear solution or which worked for me.

Code path (simplified):

1. So first a **ajax post** is made to **step3.php**
2. **Step3.php** receives post and **sets cookie**

3.

```
$array = [
    'id' => $step3->getId(),
        'array_name' => 'Rubriek',];
$register['step3'] = $array;
$newregister = $register;
$setcookie = setcookie('register', json_encode($newregister), time()+3600,'/');
$_COOKIE['register'] = json_encode($newregister);
```

4. Then the **ajax post** checks **step3.php** succeeded if is true

5.

```
window.location.href = '/wip/inschrijven/stap/4';
```

6. And on **step4.php** the first thing that happens is checking if the cookie exists

7.

```
if($_COOKIE['register']){
    $this->setRegisterCookie(json_decode($_COOKIE['register'],true));
} else {
    header('location: /wip/inschrijven/');
}
```

But this is just not working in any case; BUT when I clear cache the page loads it fine.

Even when I delete the cookie while being on the step4.php page. It firsts needs a clear cache before being able to recogonize the cookie.

**UPDATE:**

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

seems to be doing the trick, but it does not feel like a good method.

Using the no-cache the cookie is loading fine on the redirect.

Comment: When you are doing your post via ajax, try and tag on a random key/value pair to the post array.  Ie: ?random=7583367838

Some browsers cache ajax results is unpredictable ways. Anytime I use ajax I always append a generated random value.

Comment: Helps with caching probs <?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>

Comment: @VIDesignz Tried, without succes. And the ajax post happens when the user presses the next button.

Everything else is working fine, (post and the database save etc...)

Comment: @MatthewPage
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); is working!
But.. whats the side affect?

Comment: @MatthewPage any updates?

Comment: @PieterBerends why does it not feel like a good method? You're asking for the content not to be cached, I've used it plenty of times. There maybe some tricks I'm missing, but hey if it works, don't break it.